# vs code : launch.json

Tags: javascript, c, json, visual-studio-code

I'm having an issue with launch.json.
when i download vscode.
then i run(press f5 for debug) any code file , file doesn't running ...
its showing like vscode came without launch.json,task.json, setting.json..
after that i copied the launch.json from githib..
its showing error(given in picture) when I run any file of js (javascript) .

and tried to work on c++ on vscode with MingW, but vscode doesn't worked with MingW....
when i run file of c++ in vscode terminal and showing thi error : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdtWy.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1umV.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your launch file is for java script code and not for C/C++.

Please follow the instructions on Microsoft's site for VS Code:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc

or in your case:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

Your launch.json file should look something like this:

```
{
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
      "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
    }
  ],
  "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: i tried this launch.json file but still facing errors

Comment: @GautamSuthar Is this one closer to your installation?